# i want to take the 0 element of a List <> Item

Tags: c#, list

I have this declaration:

```
public class DetailList : List<Details>
```

In another part of my program I have a function:

```
DetailList List1 = new DetailList();
...
return List1;
```

which gives me error because `List1` is a `List<>` Item.
I want to return the first item of the list. Please help

Comment: `return List1[0]`? Or post the code which produces the error instead of coming up with your own version.

Comment: What is the signature of your method returning List1?

Comment: Why do you need to create a `DetailList` if it inherits from `List<Details>`?

Comment: Thank you `bit` for cleaning up the OP's grammar

Comment: You want to return the first `Details`, then use `List1.First()` or `List1[0]`. It's a little bit suprising that you know how to extend from `List<T>` but not how to use a collection.

Comment: JUst overwealmed , thanks mate that seems to work

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
return List1.FirstOrDefault();
```

This would give you the First item in your list or null if there isn't any.

Comment: Hi this tells me that 'DeatailList does not contain a definition' do you mean creat a new method in Details class that is called FirstOrDefault?

Comment: Add using System.Linq;

Answer (score 1):

First, cross check and correct the **return type** of your method. Then, use one of the following,

If the `List1` is a collection and the count is greater than zero, `return List1[0]`

or

Use `First()` when you know or expect the sequence to have at least one element

or

use `FirstOrDefault()` when you know that you will need to check whether there was an element or not